# Pull related data from JSON when Barcode scanned

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have a barcode scanner app for a warehouse.  When you scan an item, the UPC number will show, I've got that done.

But I need to now show the associated data of that UPC that will be pulled from a local JSON file (product, store, etc).

So when I **scan the barcode**, it **shows me the UPC string**, but now also needs to **show the `item` description** (i.e. "iPad mini").

`ViewController.m`

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
                    //  ...
                    [self.captureSession stopRunning];
                    self.scannedBarcode.text = capturedBarcode;
}
```

`Codes.json`:

```
{
    "codes": [
              {
                    "upc": "0885909708260",
                    "gID": "RF-001",
                    "item": "iPad mini"
              },
              {
                    "upc": "0885909746040",
                    "gID": "RF-002",
                    "item": "AirPort Extreme"
              },
              {
                    "upc": "0848447012497",
                    "gID": "RF-003",
                    "item": "powerbeats2 Wireless"
              }
              ]
}
```

Here's what I have so far to get the JSON data:

```
- (void)updateData {
    NSString *JSONFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Codes" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:JSONFilePath];
    NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    codes = JSONDictionary[@"codes"];

   // Need to finish getting the data somehow
}
```

I can't quite finish implementing, any help greatly appreciated!  Will post any extra code as necessary.

Comment: So what is your question?  You would obviously read the JSON into a database or global data structure on opening the app or on the first reference that needs the info.  (If you absolutely must you can use a "singleton" for this.) Then just keep accessing that database/structure.

Comment: @HotLicks if you can't help don't worry about it.  Or if you don't want to help don't worry about it.  Thanks!

Comment: @SRMR, your attitude isn't helpful for receiving help in the future.

Comment: I think I gave you some very substantial help above.  I will not, however, write your code for you.

Comment: @HotLicks you did help, and I appreciate the stance of not writing code for people, there's no problem here!  Thanks!

Comment: @vikingosegundo thanks for the input, I'll keep that in mind and be more aware!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is pretty straightforward. Your `codes` variable has an array of dictionaries. You need to iterate over the array and find the dictionary with the matching barcode (upc).

```
codes = ... // the array of dictionaries from the JSON data
barcode = ... // a string containing the scanned barcode

for (NSDictionary *codeData in codes) {
    NSString *upc = codeData[@"upc"];
    if ([upc isEqualToString:barcode]) {
        // do something with the matching codeData
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks just needed the clarity you gave me!  Thanks for being helpful!